# How to see steam Username by UserID?

Tags: steam

Hey guys i just created new account on steam yesterday for my brother with same email with me.
Right now i really forget the account username but i know the userID because i took screenshot in game before i lost the account so the folder with ID appear in my steam folder. i've already use email to get username but the one i got is my username not the on i just created.
So is there a way to see Username by UserID ?
Thanks

Comment: Is it even possible to create two accounts on the same email?

Comment: Nope. He probably used 2 mails. (one with hotmail and one with gmail for example, easy to forget)

Answer (score 1):

http://steamidconverter.com/

This website might come useful for you.
Just find your Community ID on this website through your SteamID and then search for it under Steam Community's Home Page -> "Find People"